# Centos7 Apache SSL

Tags: apache, ssl, ssl-certificate, centos7

I am trying to install Commodo SSL certificate and I edited /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf but my site isnt going to ssl
https://giftboundgifts.com

This is what I have in ssl.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>

# General setup for the virtual host, inherited from global configuration
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/giftboundgifts"
ServerName giftboundgifts.com
ServerAlias www.giftboundgifts.com
# Use separate log files for the SSL virtual host; note that LogLevel
# is not inherited from httpd.conf.
ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log 
TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
LogLevel warn
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5:!SEED:!IDEA
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/giftboundgifts_com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/giftboundgifts.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/giftboundgifts_com.ca-bundle
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first check that the SSL module is loaded. From the SERVER_ROOT directory, run :

```
# bin/httpd -M
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 ..
 ssl_module (shared)
 ..
```

If you don't see any ssl_module in the returned list, go to the httpd.conf and look for the LoadModule ssl_module directive and uncomment it if it's commented. Otherwise, the module is probably not here at all, and we need to check further how you installed your Apache.